# Erlang Console does not give any output (on Windows)

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I wanted to get started with erlang, so I installed it by using the binary file from their [page](https://www.erlang.org/downloads) and then I followed [this site](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse403/201110/teamRepos/HonestJimsMiracleTonic/index.html) - to execute my first erlang script.

My Problem: When I start the erlang shell everything is fine:

```
Eshell V10.6  (abort with ^G)
```

But the I start navigating, lets just say I want to go to `C:/`

```
1> cd("C:/")
```

All that happens is that there is an underscore in the next line showing up and disappearing (and showing up again and so on) - there is no reaction. I also tried that in eclipse console (created a `.erl`-module, then "executing" it which starts up the erlang console, then I navigate into the path) and the same thing happens. I do not get any visible result whatsoever, so I cannot say if there is an error or something else blocking it, maybe it was also installed in a wrong way? But I have the problem on two different devices at the moment...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end the command with a dot:

```
cd("C:/").
```

Comment: that was unexpected, but it seems to work quite fast if i use the dot afterwards - how does it come, do you know anything about that? Why there is no response if you leave it (instead of an error or something)? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It's still waiting for the dot, try to supply it after a newline.

Comment: @Rüdiger, *Why there is no response if you leave it (instead of an error or something)?* --  To make it easy to type multiline code, like a receive clause, case clause, etc., into the shell.